# How to create socket.io server without using http module?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

There is `http` module to create a server and passing express app context to it and then listening to it.
I've seen express' `app.listen` returns a Server context
Now how to create a socket.io server using `app.listen`'s context

I've tried the below code but it is not working.

```js
onst express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')

const PORT = 5000

const app = express()

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))

const io = new socket.Server(server)

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("A new socket has joined: " + socket.id)

    socket.on("hello", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

Code starts without throwing any error but the socket server is not starting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your socket server is not starting? May be you have a problem on client side...

I'm added `index.html` with client code and it connected to backend successfully.

Checkout: https://github.com/theanurin/stackoverflow.68511005

P.S.

```
Server started on port 5000
A new socket has joined: IqEjjc0dBHYSHqpMAAAB
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is with client side but im not getting why is this happening its not connecting to websocket via postman

Comment: I never used Postman as SocketIO client before... I have been tried it right now with my sample. Connection was established without any issues. I added my experience as notes in README https://github.com/theanurin/stackoverflow.68511005

Comment: Great help man! <3 Did it thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Socket IO's documentation has a section on [integrating with Express](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#Integrating-Socket-IO). Their example code looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

While still using the `http` module directly, you could perhaps replace `http.createServer(app)` with your `app.listen` call. Mind you, I'm pretty sure that `app.listen` actually uses `http.createServer` under  the hood. According to [their documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#server-attach-port-options) they do.

Comment: Yes now how to avoid `http.createServer` in such case? I belive I have a vivid remembrance of some article or some stackoverflow answer explaining how to use express itself to create socket.io server

Comment: @SwapnilSoni Is there actually a need to? If you only use `app.listen(PORT)`, it'll just use `http.createServer` internally. But according to the example from their documentation, using `io = new Server(server)` where `server = app.listen(PORT)` should work, assuming they aren't doing something hacky to `server` that influences `server.listen`.

Comment: Actually yes I need to use express' `Server` context in socket.io I know everyone suggests to use `http` module but I saw somewhere a year back and I now I lost where I saw it. I actually tried that code solution and it did worked without using `http` So after digging on the forums I still didn't found the exact answer. So I posted myself